# Can't swap object inside object of two array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Now i have two array like this

```
$arr1 = [{
fullname: 'Foo1',
info: {
   age: 18,
   country: 'HN'
   }
},
{
fullname: 'Foo2',
info: {
   age: 18,
   country: 'HN'
   }
}]
$arr2 = [{
    fullname: 'Bar1',
    info: {
       age: 18,
       country: 'HN'
       }
    },
    {
    fullname: 'Bar2',
    info: {
       age: 18,
       country: 'HN'
       }
    }]
```

Now i want swap $arr1[0] with $arr2[1] but itsn't work.
See my code

```
temp = $arr1[0];
$arr1[0] = $arr2[1];
$arr2[1] = temp;
```

when i debug $arr1[1] change before and after set = $arr2[1], but itsn't update, when i just set $arr1[0].fullname="ABC", it's update. I can't fix this bug. Please help me.

Thanks for help!

Comment: You don't have a `$arr2[2]` index. The $arr2 has 0 and 1 indexes...

Comment: @sminutoli sry, pls see update, it isn't working too

Comment: please provide a jsfiddle or codepen and we'll help you

Answer (score 3):

According to your original code snippet, you did not access array in an index based manner. `$arr1[1]` should be `$arr1[0]`. The following code should work.

```
temp = $arr1[0];
$arr1[0] = $arr2[1];
$arr2[1] = temp;
```

**Technically speaking, swapping two variables with a temporary variable `tempVar` should work.** Please try to debug your variable value with `console.log(angular.toJson($arr1));`

Comment: Sorry, i write wrong key, pls see again and it is not working too.

Comment: @hazymnc If you change your question, please add the changes to *update 1* section, otherwise later reader will not understand, why I made my initial answer.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below code. It is working fine for me.

```
$arr1 = [
    {
        fullname: 'Foo1',
        info: {
        age: 18,
        country: 'HN'
        }
    },
{
fullname: 'Foo2',
info: {
   age: 18,
   country: 'HN'
   }
}];
$arr2 = [{
    fullname: 'Bar1',
    info: {
       age: 18,
       country: 'HN'
       }
    },
    {
    fullname: 'Bar2',
    info: {
       age: 18,
       country: 'HN'
       }
    }];
    console.log($arr1[0]);
    console.log($arr2[1]);

    var temp = $arr1[0];
    $arr1[0] = $arr2[1];
    $arr2[1] = temp;

    console.log($arr1[0]);
    console.log($arr2[1]);
```

**Output**

```
sandeep@pc:~/Documents/Angular/Snippets$ node snippets.js
{ fullname: 'Foo1', info: { age: 18, country: 'HN' } }
{ fullname: 'Bar2', info: { age: 18, country: 'HN' } }
{ fullname: 'Bar2', info: { age: 18, country: 'HN' } }
{ fullname: 'Foo1', info: { age: 18, country: 'HN' } }
```